# Java: Playing sound when message revived (IP chat program)

Tags: java, audio

I know there are a lot of playing sound things. I am building a IP chat program. I am very new to programming (a nursing major if you must know). I am using eclipse. I am trying to have it play a sound when a message is received. I don't know how to make a class that will call the file and then play it. Thanks!

This is what i have right now (yes I know it is commented out):

```
public void playsound(final String input) {
   final java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
   //String stringFile = "x.wav";
   //File wavfile = new File("notification.wav");
   //AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(wavfile);
   //AudioFormat format = audioInput.getFormat();
   //DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class,  format);
   //clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `clip = AudioSystem.getClip();` with

```
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(audioInput);
clip.start();
```

removing `String stringFile = "x.wav";`

and uncommenting the rest should be sufficient.

There's a tutorial on playing files from a file inside a JAR here, which might be more useful than specifying a file in the file system: http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8c_PlayingSound.html